# Rails: defining policy with pundit that depends on which page the user is visiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, current-page, pundit

I have the same partial in rails that is required in two pages, that shows a list of posts.
The first is a news feed page, the second is a "details" page.

In the first one the user shouldn't be able to edit, in the second he should be able to.

The partial is something like that:

```
<%= best_in_place_if policy(post).update?,
                     blahblah...
                     %>
<% end %>
```

The policy is implemented like that:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  ...

  def update?
    ((@record.open? && not_blocked?) ||
    owner? ||
    collaborator?) &&
    !news_feed?
  end
  private

  def news_feed?
    current_page?(action: 'authenticated')
  end

  ...
end
```

But it seems that I can't access to method `current_page?`. Is there a way to know from policies what is the actual page I'm visiting?

Thank you

Comment: Is `current_page?` a helper method in your controller(s)/view(s)?

Comment: @Vapire api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html I tried to import it, but it have lots of dipendences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution might be to do this:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  # remove this: include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  ...

  def news_feed?
    ApplicationController.helpers.current_page?(action: 'authenticated')
  end

  ...
end
```

See [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views) and [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465083/rails-3-view-helper-method-in-model) for more.

Comment: Using `ApplicationController.helpers.current_page?` exposes you to thread safety issues with certain web servers

Comment: Could you elaborate on that and/or maybe provide a link to some resources?

Comment: Because `helpers` is a *class method*. Very useful to access the views helpers outside of the view. But the view helpers are modules and are state-less of your request. Here you try to access `current_page?` which is a method that depends on the current state of your controller (i.e the request), therefore you should get the data from the controller instance and not from any class methods/class variables. That's very basic OO thread safety considerations.

Answer (score 2):

Pundit classes does not have access to your controllers so natively you cannot call any helper that uses controller state or data. The only solution I see is to pass `action_name` as a parameter to your policy method

```
<%= best_in_place_if policy(post).my_method(action_name), ... %>
```

Then

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  # Remove this: include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def my_method(action_name)
    action_name == 'update' and ...
  end

end
```

**Edit**

I don't feel good like using `ApplicationController.helpers.current_page?` because of risks of thread safety issue on certain web servers, so I advise to pass the parameter to your policy method to eliminate all risks