# Using helpers in minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I'm trying to test my app class in using minitest but I am getting a error stating `undefined method image_path`. How can I get around this?

## app_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  setup do
    @app = apps(:app_one)
  end

  test 'should have icon_url' do
    assert(@app.icon_url == image_path('icn-medium-norm.png'))
  end
end
```

## app/models/app.rb

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_subscriptions
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :app_type }

  scope :since, ->(time) { where('created_at > ?', time) }
  scope :ios, -> { where("app_type = 'ios' ") }
  scope :android, -> { where("app_type = 'android' ") }

  def icon_url
    versions.last[:icon_url] || image_path('icn-medium-norm.png')
  end
     ...
end
```

even when I do something like

```
test 'should have icon_url' do
  assert(@app.icon_url =~ %r{.png})
end
```

I get the same error because of the app model

Comment: look [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) if it helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
assert_equal @app.icon_url, ApplicationController.helpers.image_path('icn-medium-norm.png')
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465398/429758

Comment: That error would be from the `versions.last[:icon_url] || image_path('icn-medium-norm.png')` line. View helpers are not visible in the models; you have to make the same change there as well.