# How to assert that a (delete) path - image combination is absent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

In my view I have:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("remove.png", title: "remove"), user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "This will permanently remove the user" } %>
```

I'm trying to write a test that such a link and image are absent. I've tried several versions but none seem to work. My best guess would be:

```
assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), method: :delete, count: 0
assert_select 'image_path(remove.png)', count: 0
```

The test with the first assert_select runs but counts 1 such link, while I'm pretty sure such a link is absent. I think it is counting the show method (rather than the delete method) for which a user_path(user) is indeed present.

The test with the second assert_select produces an error:

```
unexpected '.' after '["remove"]' (called from block (2 levels) in <class:SiteLayoutTest> at /test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:46)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
```

Comment: What's the situation where the image and link are absent?

Comment: They are only visible (in the index view) when it's an admin that's logged in. Otherwise they're not visible. Testing this by hand on the server seems to confirm that the code works correctly. So it seems to be the test that is incorrectly written, specifically the two assert_select lines (the rest of the test works correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assert_select "a[href=#{user_path(user)}][data-method=delete]", false, "This page must contain no delete user links"
```

**UPDATE**

The same way for image:

```
assert_select "img[src=#{image_path('remove.png')}]", false, "This page must contain no remove image"
```

In css selector (first argument) you can use any `[attr=value]` pair of html-markup element (`<... attr="value"/>`), or even combine them `[attr1=value1][attr2=value2][...]`

**UPDATE 1**

The image_path helper method is not available inside test class. A workaround is (as far as you don't have another image with 'remove' in its path):

```
assert_select "img[src*=remove]", false, "This page must contain no remove image"
```

But a better solution is not to rely on the path at all and use `class` attribute.
Inside view:

```
<%= image_tag 'remove.png', class: 'image-remove') %>
```

In test method:

```
assert_select "img.image-remove", false, "This page must contain no remove image"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for testing the link is absent. Would there also be a way for seperately testing that the image is absent?

Comment: Does it make sense? The image is inside the link tag, and is not shown when the link is hidden.

Comment: I agree for this situation. But for another test I would like to test that when logged in as admin, the link as well as the image are present. I know now how to do this for the link but not the image. I would like to test the link and image seperately because it might be that the image isn't available on the server, resulting in the link being there without the image.

Comment: Although it does work for the link, it doesn't for the image. It seems the image_path method isn't available in the test. I get the error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'image_path' for `.

Comment: It is possible. You can use the value of src attribute of img tag in resulting markup instead #{image_path(...)}. Or see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437053/using-helpers-in-minitest/29437286#29437286

Comment: I found two ways in which the test doesn't product an error message (that it, it executes the tests but the tests fail). However, in both cases according to the test the image isn't there (even though it is), so they don't seem to test for the right image/path. The two ways: `assert_select "img[src=\"ApplicationController.helpers.image_path('remove.png')\"]", true`  and  `assert_select ApplicationController.helpers.image_path('remove.png'), count: 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75212/discussion-between-andrey-turkin-and-nick).