# Include helper method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would i go about including a method, defined in my helper, in my model. The model code is as follows:

```
class Statement
  attr_accessor :opening_balance, :closing_balance 

  def initialize(acct, year = nil, month = nil)
    @db = Database.instance
    @account    = acct
    @year       = year
    @month      = month
    @month_name = Date::MONTHNAMES[@month]
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@account.number}-#{@month_name}-#{@year}"
  end

  def to_pdf
    title = @account.name
    subtitle = "Account Statement: #{@month_name} #{@year}"
    # StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, transactions).render
    StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, transactions).render
  end
end
```

I wish to include the transactions method defined in my helper.

```
def transactions(account_id, start, finish)

  response = get_call('/Accounts/Statements/' + account_id.to_s + '/' + start + '/' + finish)
  response = JSON.parse(response.body)

  @transactions = response.map do |txn| 
    Transaction.new(txn)
  end

  return @transactions

end
```

I was looking at the following solutions ([Rails 3 View helper method in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465083/rails-3-view-helper-method-in-model)) but don't know how to integrate it with my code.

Comment: You can drop `return @transactions`. It is implicitly returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the module in which your `transactions` method is defined, like this:

```
class Statement
  include NameOfTransactionModule

  attr_accessor :opening_balance, :closing_balance

  def initialize(acct, year = nil, month = nil)
    @db = Database.instance
    @account    = acct
    @year       = year
    @month      = month
    @month_name = Date::MONTHNAMES[@month]
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@account.number}-#{@month_name}-#{@year}"
  end

  def to_pdf
    title = @account.name
    subtitle = "Account Statement: #{@month_name} #{@year}"
    # StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, transactions).render
    StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, transactions).render
  end
end
```

This will make `transactions` method available as an instance method for the objects of `Statement` class.

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam I tried this by adding "include transactions" instead of "include NameOfTransactionModule". I am getting "undefined local variable or method `transactions' for Statement:Class"